# Return max value in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I need to return the maximum value of an array in Javascript, but the code doesn't work.

```
function ReturnMaxValue(listOfValues){
  max = listOfValues[0];

  for(var i in listOfValues; i < listOfValues; i++){
    if(var  i > max){
      max = i;
      return max;
  }
 }
}

ReturnMaxValue([1, 3, 5, 8, 9 , 45])
```

Comment: Remove your existing `if` statement. Replace it with `if (i > max) max = i;`. EDIT: Also, on line 2, make sure you have either `var` or `let` before max, such as `var max = blabla...`

Comment: You've got your `return` in the wrong place. You'd want it after the `for` loop finishes.

Comment: You can use Math.max:

    `Math.max(...[1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 45]);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I'm a beginner and I make a lot of nonsense, in Python it ends up being easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```js
function ReturnMaxValue(listOfValues) {
  var max = 0;

  for(let val of listOfValues){
    if(val > max) {
      max = val;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

let array = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9 , 45];
console.log( ReturnMaxValue(array) );
```

Comment: You're amazing, thank you! ❤

Comment: @BrunnaMaiaradaSilva you're welcome :) I don't know why Palash marked your question as duplicate since the answer provided here works much faster than the answer in the other question (turns out to be about 70% slower -> 
 https://jsbench.me/ggk8udw71a/2).